# Como evitar que una regex de opción múltiple no ajuste el orden de sus intentos de coincidencia a la captura de una greedy regex que se definió antes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, regex, str-replace

```py
import re

input_text = 'desde el 2022_-_12_-_10 corrimos juntas hasta el 11° nivel de aquella montaña hasta el 2022_-_12_-_13' #example 1
input_text = 'desde el 2022_-_11_-_10 18:30 pm corrimos juntas hasta el 11° nivel de aquella montaña y luego bajamos hasta la salida, hasta el 2022_-_12_-_01 21:00 hs caminamos juntas' #example 2
input_text = 'desde el 2022_-_11_-_10 18:30 pm hasta el 2022_-_12_-_01 21:00 hs' #example 3


identificate_hours = r"(?:a\s*las|a\s*la|)\s*(?:\(|)\s*(\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2})\s*(?:(am)|(pm))\s*(?:\)|)" #acepta que no se le indicase el 'am' o el 'pm'
identificate_hours = r"(?:a\s*las|a\s*la|)\s*(?:\(|)\s*(\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2})\s*(?:(am)|(pm)|)\s*(?:\)|)" #no acepta que no se le indicase el 'am' o el 'pm'

date_format = r"(?:\(|)\s*(\d*)_-_(\d{2})_-_(\d{2})\s*(?:\)|)"

#text in the middle associated with the date range...
#some_text = r"(?:(?!\.\s*?\n)[^;])*" #but cannot contain ";", ".\s*\n"
some_text = r"(?:(?!\.\s*)[^;])*" #but cannot contain ";", ".\s*"
#some_text = r"(?:[^.;])*" #but cannot contain ";", "."


identification_re_0 = r"(?:(?<=\s)|^)(?:desde\s*el|desde|del|de\s*el|de\s*la|de |)\s*(?:día|dia|fecha|)\s*(?:del|de\s*el|de |)\s*" + date_format + r"\s*(?:" + identificate_hours + r"|)\s*(?:\)|)\s*(" + some_text + r")\s*(?:,\s*hasta|hasta|al|a )\s*(?:el|la|)\s*(?:fecha|d[íi]a|)\s*(?:del|de\s*el|de|)\s*" + date_format + r"\s*(?:" + identificate_hours + r"|)\s*(?:\)|)"


input_text = re.sub(identification_re_0,
                    lambda m: (f"({m[1]}_-_{m[2]}_-_({m[3]}({m[4] or '00'}:{m[5] or '00'} {m[6] or m[7] or 'am'})_--_{m[9]}_-_{m[10]}_-_({m[11]}({m[12] or '00'}:{m[13] or '00'} {m[14] or m[15] or 'am'})))({m[8]})"),
                    input_text, re.IGNORECASE)

print(repr(input_text)) # --> output
```

Estas son las salidas incorrectas que obtengo porque la expresión regular `(?:(?!\.\s*)[^;])*` excede su rango de captura, lo que da como resultado estas cadenas incorrectas como salida.

Teniendo en cuenta la naturaleza codiciosa de las expresiones regulares por defecto, asumo que parte del problema radica en la siguiente parte de la expresión regular `\s*(?:,\s*hasta|hasta|al|a )\s*`, ya que `(?:(?!\.\s*)[^;])*` intentará encontrar una coincidencia que le permita capturar la cadena más larga que coincida con la primera cadena

La única función que debe cumplir la expresión regular `(?:(?!\.\s*)[^;])*` es capturar el texto en medio de las fechas y luego colocarlo entre paréntesis, siempre que eso el texto no contiene los signos que están excluidos en la definición.

Y esta es la salida correcta en cada uno de los casos:

```
'(2022_-_12_-_(10(00:00 am)_--_2022_-_12_-_(13(00:00 am)))(corrimos juntas hasta el 11° nivel de aquella montaña)' for the example 1
'(2022_-_11_-_(10(18:30 pm)_--_2022_-_12_-_(01(21:00 am)))(corrimos juntas hasta el 11° nivel de aquella montaña y luego bajamos hasta la salida), hs caminamos juntas' #for the example 2
'(2022_-_11_-_(10(18:30 pm)_--_2022_-_12_-_(01(21:00 am))) hs' #for the example 3
```

En este caso, me no se si exista algo que permita a la expresión regular `\s*(?:,\s*hasta|hasta|al|a )\s*` hacer sus intentos de izquierda a derecha, y no tratar de adaptarse a la posibilidad de que la parte del patrón regex definido antes pueda obtener la mayor cantidad de caracteres.

Comment: La décima pregunta sobre el mismo tema.

Comment: Uso el estandar de pregunta, para no cambiar lel formato porque se que esta bien organizada, "input", "code intermedio", y "outputs deseados". Aunque este creo que es un problema de greedy regex

Comment: La pregunta no tiene objeciones; es que llevas tiempo iterando sobre el mismo problema, repitiendo la misma pregunta con ligeras variaciones. Eso debería decirte que vas por el camino equivocado. Se te han ofrecido soluciones más simples que has ignorado.

Comment: olo queda ir por regex, por la complejidad del problemaPuede que halla soluciones mas simples, pero en este caso creo que s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que estás buscando es que

```
(?:(?!\.\s*)[^;])*
```

coincida de forma no codiciosa (*lazy*), lo que hay que hacer es modificar el cuantificador `*` por `*?`.

```
(?:(?!\.\s*)[^;])*?
```

El `?` extra después de cualquier cuantificador (`*?`, `+?`, `??`, `{2,5}?`, etc) modifica el comportamiento para que intente coincidir con lo menos posible.

Sin embargo, analizando con un poco más de detalle, los espacios después del punto no son obligatorios: `(?!\.\s*)` va a ser siempre lo mismo que `(?!\.)`... Y por lo tanto, toda la expresión siempre va ser lo mismo que

```
[^;.]*?
```